# Getting "Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor with 63984 bytes from a Java Buffer with 64000 bytes" error passing I/O TensorAudio to TFLite model

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, speech-recognition, tensorflow-lite

I am getting the following error while loading the input and output audio buffers to tensorflow-lite interpreter for inferencing. I am using the TensorAudio and TensorAudioFormat packages from the tflite-support.audio package. The tflite-lite model I am using is trained for audio samples with a 16kHz sample rate and mono channel. Please take a look at the code below.

```
float audioData [] = wavObj.ReadingAudioFile(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()+ "/final_record.wav");
float [] outputBuffer;
TensorAudioFormat.Builder audioFormat = TensorAudioFormat.builder();
audioFormat.setChannels(1);
audioFormat.setSampleRate(16000);
TensorAudio tensorAudio = TensorAudio.create(audioFormat.build(), audioFormat.build().getSampleRate());
tensorAudio.load(audioData);
tflite.run(tensorAudio.getTensorBuffer().getBuffer(), outputBuffer);
```

Here, **wavObj.ReadingAudioFile** is returning the audio buffer for the saved audio file. I am using TensorAudioFormat to explicitly set the channel type and sample rate to match the trained model. I have load the tflite-trained model into tflite Interpreter using the below code.

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd(modelPath); 
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()); 
FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel(); 
long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(); 
long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength(); 
ByteBuffer model = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength); 
Interpreter.Options options = new Interpreter.Options(); 
tflite = new Interpreter(model, options);
```

Please suggest a solution to this problem.

The TFlite model Interpreter should accept the audioBuffer for wav file and return the label id for the output classification.